# Data Contract for a JSON request with dynamic key names in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to create a Web Service in WCF that takes as POST data, a complex JSON object, with parts of it being sub-objects with dynamic keys. For example,

```
{
    "documents": [{
        "ID": "reqOne",
        "context": { 
            "source": "data1",
            "user": "data2",
            "eventName": "data3"
        },
        "data": ["1", "2", "3"]
    },{
        "ID": "reqTwo",
        "context": {
            "source": "data1",
            "user": "data2",
            "date": "data3"
        },
        "data": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    }]
}
```

This is how my data contract looks like.

```
[DataContract]
public class MLWebRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<MLRequestItem> documents;
}

[DataContract]
public class MLRequestItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID;

    [DataMember(Name = "context", IsRequired = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> context { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> data;
    public MLRequestItem()
    {
        context = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

This is how my interface for that specific request has been defined.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
MLWebResponse Serve(MLWebRequest request);
```

This is not working for me. I've taken a look at this answer:
[C# data contract for complex JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731028/c-sharp-data-contract-for-complex-json-object)

And it seems to me from one of the answers that a `Dictionary<string, string>` should suffice if I know that my JSON object does not contain duplicate keys.

The `MLWebRequest` I receive in the `Serve` method has all the other fields populated correctly, but the `context` dictionary of all `MLRequestItem`s contains zero elements.

I'm on .NET 4.6 on Windows 10. I can't figure out another way to get this to work short of requiring the client to serialize the sub-object first and send it to me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: Also tried to change the datatype of a context to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` - didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally advised by someone that WCF is outdated, and no longer maintained, and `ASP.NET Core 2.0` is a more modern platform to host a service on the .NET stack.

Turned out to be true and the same C# Class (it's a `Model` in ASP parlance, and not a `Data Contract`) worked without throwing any fits.

It is also a lot easier to set up an `ASP.NET` boilerplate to send and receive JSONs, compared to WCF where you have to toggle some arcane config tags, so I'll highly recommend `ASP.NET Core` to anyone reading this.