# how can to parse in c# JSON with dynamic key using JSON.NET or any other package

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, jsonparser

Hi guys i am having problem how can i parse JSON with this data because as you can see below the data_0 key is incrementing i am having confusion how can i parse it using my models

```
{
"status": {
    "connection_status": "successful",
    "operation_status": "successful",
    "Customer": {
        "data_0": {
            "id": "123321",
            "FirstName": "testFirstname",
            "LastName": "testlastname"
        },
        "data_1": {
            "id": "321123",
            "FirstName": "testFirstname",
            "LastName": "testlastname",
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is my model

```
public class GetAccountBalanceResponseModel
{
    public Stat status { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string connection_status { get; set; }
    public string operation_status { get; set; }
    public Custmer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Custmer
{
    public Datas data { get; set; } -- i am having problem with this one 
}

public class Datas
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string accountBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem to this `Datas data { get; set; }` and what do you mean `How can i parse it`?

Comment: my problem is how can i put the data_0, data_1 in one class as you can see the JSON response has an incremental value i might want to put it in one class

Comment: You can you dynamic data type instead of class for this above json.

Comment: @Mano can you give some example for what you mean?

Comment: ok so classical dupe. 1rst step is to get the general id of the json. Use either Json2 csharp or Visual studio special past.

Comment: @xdtTransform i actually did but json2csharp returns class 2 classes Data1 and Data2 i want to make it as 1 class either because in the time i am inserting data to the api the response will always increment like data_0, data_1, data_2 etc...

Comment: You data_X can be deserialise in dictionary <string,object> then map to  a simple list, Or write an Custome deserliser with a json property on this. You see 3 know basic Json question: How to deserialise/ Dictionary <strings,T> / Custom Parser

Comment: I try to google "data1 data2 json c#", and got hit by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731028/c-sharp-data-contract-for-complex-json-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize complex JSON object using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187996/deserialize-complex-json-object-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<string, Datas>` for property `Customer` in `Stat` class,

```
public class Stat
{
    public string connection_status { get; set; }
    public string operation_status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Datas> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
GetAccountBalanceResponseModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetAccountBalanceResponseModel>(json);    

foreach (var item in model.status.Customer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Value.id);
    Console.WriteLine("FirstName: " + item.Value.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine("LastName: " + item.Value.LastName);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just change your `Stat` class a little:

```
public class Stat
{
    public string connection_status { get; set; }
    public string operation_status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Datas> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use something like `stat.Customer["data_0"].email`