# Using C# DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize a string property that contains a json. Throws XmlException

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm trying to deserialize a class that has a string property called Metadata that contains a json.

I don't want to deserialize whatever is in that json, I just want to copy that text to my string property. I don't have a say how the jsonString looks like because it's being returned by a web service.

I'm getting an exception:

> XmlException: End element 'metadata' from namespace '' expected. Found
> element 'key' from namespace ''.

Code sample:

```
[DataContract]
public class YourClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "metadata", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember(Name = "anotherProperty", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Your JSON string
        string jsonString = "{\"metadata\":{\"key\":\"value\"}, \"anotherProperty\":42}";

        // Create a MemoryStream from the JSON string
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            // Create an instance of DataContractJsonSerializer for your class
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YourClass));

            // Deserialize the JSON string to your class
            YourClass obj = (YourClass)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

            // Access the deserialized property
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731028/c-sharp-data-contract-for-complex-json-object and [JSON to Data Contract (or JSON.NET) types](https://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: To help you figure out the proper code, I recommend serializing first. Once you get serialization working properly (ie: it matches the expected format), then deserialization should work as well.

Comment: @user246821 serialization works as expected, serializer understands that the data is a string when serializing. Unfortunately that doesn't help me with deserialization. Also I've already went through that link you provided and unfortunately they don't solve my issue. But thank you for the effort nonetheless.

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` doesn't support deserialization of free-form JSON.  For one thing, its base class `XmlObjectSerializer` is designed to deserialize **XML**, and the reader returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader) works by [transcoding JSON to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml)...

Comment: ... And in general the data contract serializers don't provide the ability to bind in converters that have access to the underlying XML or JSON token stream.  Can you switch to another serializer?  Almost every other JSON serializer you might choose could do this.  Both Json.NET and System.Text.Json can do this easily, for example.

Comment: For instance, for Json.NET see [Efficiently get full json string in JsonConverter.ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56944160).  For System.Text.Json see [Is there an equivalent for JRaw in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60931870).

Comment: @dbc Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, without some major refactoring I'm stuck with this serializer, it's an older codebase that has to compile for a bunch of frameworks. Well, I'll have to figure something out. Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: @NKatic - do you need to deserialize both XML and JSON with the same classes, or just JSON?

Comment: @dbc just JSON web responses, no xml required.